# std::min_element returning unexpected result

Tags: c++, c++11, min, std

I want to find the minimum of a vector:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    vector<double> v{2, 0, 4};
    double minT = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end(),
                                    [](double i1, double i2) {
                                        std::cout << "Comparing: " << i1 << "  " << i2 << "   " << ((i1 < i2)? i1:i2) << "    " << '\n';
                                        return (i1 < i2)? i1:i2;
                                    });
    cout << "Minimum is: " << minT << '\n';
}
```

But the output of this piece of code is:

```
Comparing: 0  2   0    
Comparing: 4  2   2    
Minimum is: 4
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any undefined behaviour there?

**NOTE**: I know I do not need the lambda function. Removing it returns the expected result (0), but my goal is to have a personalized min function which does not consider zeros.

Comment: Worth pointing out that your function is not stable. That is, if two elements are equal, you probably want to get the first; your code will get the second. You might want to consider `!(i2<i1)`. (Not a requirement though)

Comment: @BoBTFish thanks for the note, but I do not see how that makes it not stable. Could you give an example please? In may case, since I only want the value I do not really care about position, but just in case.

Comment: "Stable" is a bad word, since it really refers to sorting, in that a stable sort keeps equal elements in their original order. But say your container has `{1, 1, 1}`. Your `min_element` (once fixed) returns an iterator to the *last* `1`, when most people would probably expect the first.

Comment: @BoBTFish Oh I see, you meant that kind of stable. In my actual code, since I am dealing with `double` I am doing `i1+MARGIN < i2`. Do you think it is necessary in this case?

Comment: That's a whole different world. I would suspect you don't really want to use an epsilon here, but that's probably worth a new question. Where do these doubles come from?

Comment: @BoBTFish: That's an interesting observation, but why do you think most people would expect an iterator to the first element?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Partly because that's what [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) do when used without a custom comparator, and partly because finding min/max elements is closely related to ordering, and given a sorted container and told to find the smallest element, I would just grab the first element. The second reason depends on the assumption that other people think remotely like me, however.

Comment: @BoBTFish those doubles can have actually very close, but different values since they are computed from complex interpolations.

Comment: An epsilon is usually used when wanting to consider close values as equal. Not sure it makes sense for ordering. That's a genuine "not sure" - I really don't know what you should do here. Suggest making a new question with more detail. Search first of course, might be answered already.

Comment: epsilon-comparisons do not provide a strict weak ordering and hence are not valid comparators for standard algorithms.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The comparator needs to return `true` if the first argument is less than the second, not the smaller of the two values. So the return statement should just be

```
return i1 < i2;
```